# spring boot no converter found for return type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing my first spring boot application and getting the following error. 
The spring boot should have the correct json converter jars and shouldn't throw this kind of error. ?

> Failed to write HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No
>   converter found for return value of type: class
>   com.test.userservice.models.dto.Response

My Response class

```
public class Response {

    String code;

    String message;

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Rest controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/register")
 public ResponseEntity<Response> registerUser(){

        Response x = new Response();
        x.setCode("test");
        x.setMessage("message");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(x, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

I did the small search and added this dependencies to the pom also. Still having an error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What could the issue ?
Thanks

Comment: Don't you have getters in your Response class? Try adding those.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the getter and working fine. I think converter requires the getter and setter ?

Comment: Yes, IIUC the mapping relies on reflection to retrieve method names conforming to the bean standard.

Comment: Vish K, in case of your first spring boot app, let me give you one remark regard usage of ResponseEntity. In typical cases wrapping is redundant. Your endpoint can return just Response object, but your controller should be marked with @RestController annotation (Instead of just @Controller)